# Problemas com Frames em Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade, e estou com dificuldades em mexer com `Frames`, mais precisamente preciso construir o grafo abaixo.

No código, você anda por ele a partir de comandos *LESTE, OESTE, NORTE e SUL*, mas por exemplo quando estou no ponto *3* e dou o comando *LESTE*, ele está indo para o ponto *9* e não sei o motivo e não consigo encontrar o erro no código.

[image: Grafo]

```
from tkinter import *

class Shakespeare:
    cont1=0
    pontos=0
    comando=''
    quarto=0
    flag7=0
    dvivo=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        self.quarto1()

    def saiu_do_sete(self):
        if(Shakespeare.flag7==1):
            self.msg = Label(self.c, text='Há um emblema na parede, rasgado, como se o fogo houvesse arrancado o olho de um animal')
        Shakespeare.flag7=0   

    def quarto1(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        self.saiu_do_sete()
        Shakespeare.quarto=1
        Shakespeare.cont1+=1
        self.msg =Label(self.c,text='Já é noite e você finalmente encontra abrigo em uma caverna escura'
                        ' e fria. Após explorá-la por algum tempo, você encontra um caldeirão fumegando. Ao estalo de um trovão, três bruxas surgem diante de você.')
        self.msg.pack()       
        if(Shakespeare.cont1==1):
            self.msg =Label(self.c,text='As bruxas falam eu uma só voz: \n\n'
                            'Mortal, te convocamos, deixe de lado o medo!\n'
                            'Apressa-te em tua missão, não sede hesitante.\n'
                            'Ache olhos de salamandra e sapo, um dedo\n'
                            'E os jogue aqui nesse caldeirão fumegante!\n\n'
                            'E mais: asas da coruja que aqui ousava voar,\n'
                            'Perna de lagarto e pelo de gato Angara.\n'
                            'Essas coisas precisamos para o feitiço lançar!\n'
                            'Rápido, nos traga e mal nenhum te abaterá\n\n'
                            'Pois agora nos deixe e vá embora.\n'
                            'Nada mais temos a dizer no momento\n'
                            'A não ser te avisar que lá fora\n'
                            'Um dragão pode ser o teu tormento!')
            self.msg.pack()
        else:
            Shakespeare.pontos+=1
            self.msg = Label(self.c, text='As bruxas estão diante de você, com olhos arregalados, esperando que lhes dê algo. '
                             'Os sons da noite parecem lhe avisar que não é seguro neste lugar continuar.')
            self.msg.pack()
        self.msg= Label(self.c, text='Você pode ir ao NORTE, SUL, LESTE ou OESTE')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def ok(self):
        Shakespeare.comando=self.e.get()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==7):
            Shakespeare.flag7=1

        if Shakespeare.comando=="NORTE" or Shakespeare.comando=="SUL" or Shakespeare.comando=="LESTE" or Shakespeare.comando=="OESTE":
            self.ir_para(Shakespeare.comando)

    def ir_para(self,comando):
        print(Shakespeare.quarto, comando)

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="NORTE"):
            self.quarto3()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto8()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto5()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto6()

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==2 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto2()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==2 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto2()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==2 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto3()

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==3 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto1()        
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==3 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto4()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==3 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto2()              

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==4 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto6()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==4 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto6()

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==5 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto1()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==5 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto7()           

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==6 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto9()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==6 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto1()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==6 and comando=="NORTE"):
            self.quarto4()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==6 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto8()            

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==7 and comando=="NORTE"):
            self.quarto2()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==7 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto5()

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==8 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto6()

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==9 and comando=="NORTE"):
            self.quarto6()
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==9 and comando=="OESTE"):
            self.quarto10()            

        if(Shakespeare.quarto==10 and comando=="LESTE"):
            self.quarto9()

    def quarto2(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=2
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c, text='Q2 Você voltou no tempo... Parece estar em um castelo medieval na Europa no século XIV.\n\n'
                         'Há brasões e emblemas nas paredes cheias de mofo. Em um dos emblemas, você vê o que parece ser um animal no meio do fogo.'
                         ' Abaixo uma inscrição diz "vulcani" e, mais abaixo, "Paracelso". Por um momento, o animal parece estar olhando em seus olhos.\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao SUL, LESTE ou OESTE')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()  


    def quarto3(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=3
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c, text='Q3 Um mundo, um paradigma, a sociedade, cachorros, aviões, mortes, cachorros-quente, viagens, alucinógenos\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao SUL, LESTE ou OESTE ')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()        

    def quarto4(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=4
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q4 Ventos fortes, ventos fracos, ventos, ventanias, vendavais, vendas\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao SUL ou LESTE')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto5(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=5
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q5 Hoje, mas não amanhã, somente hoje, eu irei, mas somente se não chover, porque senão não fará sol, então'
                         ' haveria de ser amanhã, mas hoje será o que ontem não foi\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao LESTE ou OESTE ')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto6(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=6
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q6 O demônio, números, bodes, bandeiras esquisitas, Guiné e a socideade, tudo a mesma coisa, só que diferente\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao NORTE, SUL, LESTE ou OESTE ')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto7(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=7
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q7 Você se encontra em um lugar onde o grupo Monty Python está encenando o "Sapo Crocante".'
                         ' Você olha para um confeiteiro que logo lhe diz: "Se eu tirar os ossos, eles não vão ser mais crocantes,'
                         ' né?" Você então vê uma caixa de chocolate onde está escrito "Sapos Crocantes". Ela parece conter uma dúzia'
                         ' de sapos inteiros, cuidadosamente cobertos pelo melhor chocolate.\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao NORTE ou OESTE ')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto8(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=8
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q8 Uma porta, somente uma porta que pode ser aberta, irei morrer agora? Ou será só o reinício dessa história?\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao LESTE')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto9(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=9
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q9\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao NORTE ou OESTE ')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

    def quarto10(self):
        self.c.destroy()
        self.c=Frame(w, width=500, height=500)
        self.c.pack()
        Shakespeare.quarto=10
        Shakespeare.pontos+=1
        self.msg = Label(self.c,text='Q10 Você está em uma cozinha. Você então vê, ao fundo, um cozinheiro colocando uma porção de atum em uma'
                         ' panela. \nApesar de não ter certeza, parece haver uma espingarda ao lado do fogão. Há pelos brancos voando por todo lado,'
                         ' enquanto o cozinheiro parece falar sozinho: "Impossível trabalhar com todos estes gatos aqui...\n'
                         'Você pode ir ao LESTE')
        self.msg.pack()
        self.e = Entry(self.c)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(self.c,text="OK",command=self.ok)
        self.b.pack()

w=Tk()
app = Shakespeare()
w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente o número do quarto é *1*.

```
def quarto1(self):
    # ...
    Shakespeare.quarto=1
    # ....
```

Na primeiro `Frame` que é exibido se você digitar *LESTE*, no método `ir_para`, a linha abaixo é executada:

```
if(Shakespeare.quarto == 1 and comando == "LESTE"):
    self.quarto6()
```

No método `quarto6` o valor da variável `Shakespeare.quarto` é alterada:

```
def quarto6(self):
    # ...
    Shakespeare.quarto = 6
    # ....
    self.b = Button(self.c, text="OK", command = self.ok)
```

Ao ser concluído a execução do método `quarto6` a variável `Shakespeare.quarto` tem como valor *6*.

O método `ir_para` **vai continuar sua execução**, é ai que pode estar o problema, como o comando é *LESTE* e o quarto agora é *6*, logo o motivo de estar indo para o ponto *9* é:

```
if(Shakespeare.quarto == 6 and comando == "LESTE"):
    self.quarto9()
```

Você entra no quarto *X*, altera para *X* o valor de `Shakespeare.quarto` e continua com a execução do método `ir_para`. Uma forma de corrigir isso é colocar um [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) após chamar a outra função:

```
 if(Shakespeare.quarto == 1 and comando == "LESTE"):
     self.quarto6()
     return
```

Também é necessário fazer o mesmo em outras partes do código que apresentem esse comportamento.

Uma outra forma é colocar o código num bloco `while` e usar o [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) para parar a execução:

```
def ir_para(self,comando):
    print(Shakespeare.quarto, comando)

    while True:
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="NORTE"):
            self.quarto3()
            break
        if(Shakespeare.quarto==1 and comando=="SUL"):
            self.quarto8()
            break
        # ...
        # ....
        # .....
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, mano, realmente passou batido este erro, vlw!!!